# Remove URL parameter if no checkboxes are selected

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms

I'm attempting to setup some basic filtering on a page using the following script. However, if the user unchecks all boxes, the page refreshes with a blank `areas` parameter. How can I check against this happening and therefore remove the `areas` query in the URL if no checkboxes are selected?

Thanks.

```
(function($) {
                    $('#filters').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {

                        // vars
                        var $ul = $(this).closest('ul'),
                        vals = [];

                    $ul.find('input:checked').each(function(){
                        vals.push( $(this).val() );
                    });

                    vals = vals.join(",");

                    window.location.replace('<?php echo home_url('casestudies'); ?>?areas=' + vals );
                    console.log(vals);



                });
            })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code before  *vals = vals.join(",");*

```
if( vals.length == 0 ){
    window.location.replace('<?php echo home_url('casestudies'); ?>');                  
}
```

Comment: Just needed to add an additional if statement around the original declaration and it worked perfectly. Thanks!